# Вопрос о "статических" переменных

Tags: jquery, javascript, wordpress, php

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема: выучил начальный курс javascript и jquery. Теперь с написанием скрипта, экспорта картинок, столкнулся с проблемой. Дело в том, что мой проект стоит на WordPress и мне нужно, чтобы в каждой моей записи была уникальная "статическая" переменная. То есть, например, есть запись 1 и в коде именно для этой записи есть уникальная переменая, которая никогда не меняется, так же для записей 2,3,4. Может быть для этого нужно сохранять переменную через php в базу данных, а потом выводить ее через JavaScript и работать с ней? Подскажите, я не знаю.
Спасибо.

Так же прошу, может кто нибудь мне может рассказать как "связывать" два языка Java Script и PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

собственно а что мешает использовать стандартную ID записи??? Она уникальная для каждой страницы... а в Js код можно её просто передавать...

```
<script>
var a = <?php global $post; echo $post->ID; ?>
</script>
```

но в таком случае этот скрипт должен быть в шапке... а не в отдельном JS файлике... что не есть хорошо...

Answer (score 0):

Можно передавать переменные в адресе:

```
http://www.somesite.com/script.js?a=5&b=6
http://www.somesite.com/script.php?a=5&b=6
```

только с кирилицей будут проблемы т.к веб почемуто разработан так будто все пользуются DOS и в адресе поддерживается лишь 256 символов

***UPD:***
В PHP обращятся так : $_REQUEST['имя переменной'] такой метод называется POST им всё передаётся в адресной строке ещё есть метод GET но про него вы наверное читали сами :)
а в JavaScript можно просто обратится к переменной по имени

***UPD***

```
define("pi",3.14); // Обьявляет константу pi=3.14
echo pi; // Выведет 3.14
pi=5; // pi так и останется 3.14
echo pi; // Выведет 3.14
```

Константа это 'переменная' которую нельзя изменить после обьявления

Comment: на счет связи разобрался всем спасибо. До сих пор не могу понять о переменной. Допустим, есть 200 страниц сайта, мне нужно, чтобы на КАЖДОЙ странице создавалась РАЗНАЯ переменная, которая НИКОГДА ни при каких условиях не МЕНЯЛАСЬ. Просто была и в нужном мне месте выводилась. НАпример, для страниы 1 была переменная page1, для 2й - page2. Как такое сделать?

Comment: Пам помогут константы см. UPD к моему ответу

Answer (score -1):

Ну связать переменную JS c переменной PHP можно так, например:

```
<?php
$a = 3;
echo("<script>a=$a</script>") 
?>
```

А вот чтобы связать переменную PHP с переменной JS, придется попотеть...но можно попробовать использовать динамический Javascript - AJAX.

Comment: echo пишется без скобочек уже давно

Comment: Подскажите кто знает - в какой версии echo писался со скобочками? Люблю историю просто... :D

Comment: Помоему В PHP3 ...